# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905 -> throw err;

Tags: node.js, npm, fedora, nvm, n

- **Node.js Version**: v14.17.3
- **OS**:  Fedora 34 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
- **Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?)**:  `node init`

Just tried to initialize node at local directory

```sh
❯ node init
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/searge/Dev/Learn/GoIT/Webpack/init'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []

❯ nvm list
->     v14.17.3
default -> lts/* (-> v14.17.3)

❯ npm -v
7.19.1
```

First, I have installed `n` version manager with same problem, so I've installed `nvm`, but error the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is no such command `node init`, you can't init node as it is already installed on your system. You might need to use `npm init` or `npm i` to initialise the `package.json`;

`npm init <initializer>` can be used to set up a new or existing npm package.

`initializer` in this case is an npm package named `create-<initializer>`, which will be installed by `npm-exec`, and then have its main bin executed -- presumably creating or updating package.json and running any other initialization-related operations

For more details check [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-init) docs.

Comment: It happens as there are a lot of similar sounding init commands.

Answer (score 0):

- open

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming  and delete the NPM folder
this Roaming folder carry cache and this needs to be delete
you have to type the above mentioned path to find the npm folder